# vuetify <v-list-tile> element does not apply color attribute

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following list setup but am not able to set a color for a `v-list-tile` it appears to stay uncolored. This is the template:

```
 <v-container>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-card color="rgba(75,75,75,1)">
          <v-card-title><h4>Details</h4></v-card-title>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-list dense>
            <v-list-tile v-for="(value,key) in testData" dark color="rgba(85,85,85,1)">
              <v-list-tile-content >{{key}}</v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">{{value}}</v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-container>
```

[image]

This the result.
Only `v-card` seems to apply the color attribute
everything below the `v-divider` does not change it's color

Answer (score 0):

In a v-list-tile the color attribute changes the color of the text only.

If you want to style the background it is easiest to use an inline style.

```
<v-list-tile
  style="background-color:rgba(85,85,85,1)"
  ...
</v-list-tile>
```